# How to generate a simple chart using data from database?

Tags: php, mysql, charts

I'd like to generate a simple bar chart to portray the number of users in different countries.
These are the data in my `user` table.

[image]

The query to count the total number of users in each country are as follows:

`SELECT country.country, COUNT( user.id) FROM user join country on user.country_id=country.country_id GROUP BY country.country`

This is the output:

[image]

Now, how do I put this to create a bar chart linked to the database and not just hardcoding the data?

Comment: 1) slurp in data from query 2) feed data to charting library 3) display chart.

Comment: Depends on your target. Usually you can copy that table. Paste it in Excel and create a chart. Or copy it in a text file, save it as csv and use Mathematica, matlab, gnuplot, .... the list is endless

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Business Intelegance platform/software.

or

You can use PHP, JavaScript combo and display it dynamically and graphically using something like, [D3js.org](http://www.D3js.org)

Answer (score 1):

It would require some programming, but these APIs are pretty nice...

[Google Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/)

[YUI Charts](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/charts/)

EDIT: YUI is no longer maintained.

Answer (score 1):

Create a method in PHP that runs your SQL queries and returns you the data you want to use in the chart. Encode and return the data in json format.

Using javascript make a post request to the method you made above and use the response as the data to create your chart.

[Google Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/) is fairly simple to use.